# How to pass in the context data from model in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'm in view (View1) with model1 and i want pass something through context to template. I have a problem because I want to pass data from another model and I don't know how to refer to it:

```
class View1():

    model = model1
   
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context_data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context_data['mycontext'] = # i want to pass data from model3_field1
```

model1:

```
class model1():
    some_fields..
```

model2:

```
class model2():

    model2_field1 = models.ForeignKey(model1, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

    model2_field2 = models.ForeignKey(model3, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
```

model3:

```
class model3()

    model3_field1 = models.CharField(default=YesNo.NO,  max_length=4, blank=True, choices=YesNo.choices)
```

Comment: What kind of view is `View1`? It looks like it is a `DetailView`? For a `model1` object, there can be zero, one or more related `model3`s...

Answer (score 0):

> I want to pass data from another model and I don't know how to refer to it.

Your `model2` acts as a junction table between `model1` and `model3`, this thus means that for a single `model1` object, there can be zero, one or multiple related `model3`s. So it is possible there are no related `model3`, a single one that is yes or no, two that are both yes, two where one is yes and one is no, two that are no, three that are …. So accessing the `model3_field1` makes no sense.

You can obtain all the related `model3`s if your view is a `DetailView` with:

```
from django.views.generic import DetailView


class View1(DetailView):
    model = model1

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context_data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context_data['mycontext'] = Model3.objects.filter(
            model2__model1=self.object
        )  # can be a collection of zero, one or more Model3s
        return context_data
```